# Does $\varprojlim_{t\mapsto t^p}\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, rigid-analytic-spaces

Consider the following inverse system (edit: say category of multiplicative monoids or sets)
\begin{equation}
\cdots\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\xrightarrow{t\mapsto t^p}\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\cdots
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{C}$ is complex numbers. The inverse limit is
\begin{equation}
\varprojlim_{t\mapsto t^p}\mathbb{C}=(a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_{i-1},a_i,\ldots)
\end{equation}
such that $a_i^p=a_{i-1}$. Intuitively this is $(a,a^{1/p},a^{1/p^2},\ldots)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$, this can be multiplied with another tuple $(b,b^{1/p},b^{1/p^2},\ldots)$ to get $(ab,a^{1/p}b^{1/p},a^{1/p^2}b^{1/p^2},\ldots)$ giving it a structure of a multiplicative monoid.

In my opinion the universal property of inverse limit and algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}$ should give $\mathbb{C}$ back. In other words the inverse limit described above should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as a multiplicative monoid, i.e. instead of a tuple we should be just able to say $\mathbb{C}$.

**Question**: Is this true?

**Sketch Proof [edited]**: Let $\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$ be a copy of $\mathbb{C}$ and a candidate for inverse limit and $a_0\in \color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$. Then consider a set theoretic map $a_0\mapsto a_i$ for $\mathbb{C}$ at $i$th position in the inverse system. This gives projection from $\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$ to every $\mathbb{C}$ in the inverse system (See below).

\begin{equation}
\cdots\underset{a_i}{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \underset{a_{i-1}}{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \cdots
\end{equation}

We need to show that universal property is satisfied, for this consider the map $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$ as $(a_0,a_1,\ldots)\rightarrow a_0$, and the natural projections from $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}$ agree with natural projections from $\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$ by construction. Now, the universal property of $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}$ gives the result as $\color{red}
{\mathbb{C}}$. All maps are in {Sets}.

**EDIT**

1. The above holds for an algebraically closed field $k$ of char $p$, that is replace $k$ with $\mathbb{C}$ above, that is $\varprojlim_{t\mapsto t^p}k=k$.
2. Intuitively the tuple $(a_0=a,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ in the inverse limit is just $(a,a^{1/p},a^{1/p^2},\ldots)$.
3. The question arises from the fact that there are two tuples corresponding to $1\in\mathbb{C}$. First the tuple $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ and second, the tuple $(1,\zeta_p,\zeta_{p^2},\ldots)$ where $\zeta_d$ is the $d$th root of unity. It seems to me that the sketch proof takes care of this by making a choice of a tuple.
4. One can consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a monoid with multiplication as group operation and $t\mapsto t^p$ as the homomorphism, or simply work with group $\mathbb{C}^\times$. In this case there is a clear projection map

\begin{equation}
(ab,a^{1/p}b^{1/p},a^{1/p^2}b^{1/p^2},\ldots)\mapsto ab
\end{equation}
respecting the multiplication.

Comment: Which category are you taking the inverse limit in?

Comment: May be just start with Sets and then move onto Fields.

Comment: $t\mapsto t^p$ is certainly not a field homomorphism on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Please note that there is an isomorphism for algebraically closed field $k$ for char p. i.e. replace $\mathbb{C}$  with $k$ above.

Comment: @har_b I'm not sure you know what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to compute the tilt of $\mathbb{C}$? If you are taking the limit as multiplicative monoids then this limit over a field $K$ computes the multiplicative monoid of its tilt. The addition won't make sense though for the complex topology. In short, can you explain why you're trying to compute this.

Comment: @AlexYoucis This is analogue of tilt, but I want to know if the definition over complex numbers gives complex numbers back.

Comment: @har_b You take the limit over monoids in the tilting operation. How do you propose you define an addition on this colimit.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I just want to use the definition of Inverse Limit (as in wikipedia) and define a map from $\varprojlim \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies commutativity and then the universal property of inverse limit gives the answer.

Comment: Your "Sketch Proof" makes no sense to me; I can't even tell what you are trying to prove.  It appears you are defining ${\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}}$ to be the inverse limit and then proving it is the inverse limit, which is trivial...

Comment: @EricWofsey The two Cs have different colours. Quite a particular choice, but I think the OP means those two Cs are different...

Comment: I think it’s very reasonable to do this in the category of topological spaces, and in that case I’m pretty sure you get something very different from $\Bbb C$.

Comment: To emphasis the comment of @EricWofsey, your proof only shows that $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}$ is $\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$ (which is true by definition of $\color{red}{\mathbb{C}}$), whereas what you are are *asking* is whether $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}$ "is" $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have edited the proof for more clarity. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for an answer. I have added point 4 in the edits, where we can consider the group $\mathbb{C}^\times$. Does this help in giving an isomorphism .

Comment: @LeeMosher Can we conclude that atleast set theoretically $\varprojlim\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: No mathematician would say that, just as they would not say $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb C$ based solely on the fact that they have the same cardinality. The very first comment by @AnginaSeng is very pertinent here: tell us what category you wish to take the inverse limit in; then we can try to answer what object in that category the inverse limit is **isomorphic to** (avoiding the word **is**).

Comment: @LeeMosher: I think the topological inverse limit should be more complicated--restricting to $S^1$, the inverse limit would be a $p$-adic solenoid, not just the universal cover $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, that's a very good point. I think I'll just get rid of that comment.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your time. I am looking over monoids in particular, this type of limit is taken in perfectoid rings with inverse limit being a multiplicative monoid. I want to see how it works over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @har_b There is no real question here. If you're talking about just abstract fields then $\mathbb{C}_p\cong \mathbb{C}$. The multiplicative monoid $\varprojlim \mathbb{C}$ over the pth power map is just isomorphic multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{C}_p^\flat$. Of course, to define the addition you need to talk about $p$-adic convergance and then you're not going to be able to do anything without identifying it with $\mathbb{C}_p$. In short: tilting works for topological fields for which $p$ is topologically nilpotent--it's not an operation you can apply to arbitrary fields.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have explicitly computed the inverse limit in the question above, is it possible to show that it is isomorphic at least as a multiplicative monoid to $\mathbb{C}$.(obviously 2 is problem)

Answer (score 3):

no this is not true. first, let us just look at everything as sets.as you noted in (3) the p-th power map is not injective over $\mathbb{C}$ so we do not have a canonical isomorphism between the inverse limit and $\mathbb{C}$. note that in field of char p case p-th power map is injective.

I think you still can find an isomorphism because these are sets and are determined only by their cardinality. but $\mathbb{C}$ has other structures as well. if you look at the multiplicative structure the p-th power  map must be an isomorphism on the inverse limit so the inverse limit can not be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as monoids. and  I don't know whether you can define a good additive structure on the inverse limit or not.

in fact know that I think about it we have an interesting ring structure on the inverse limit. if you forget about the topology $\mathbb{C}$ then it is the same as $C_p$: the completion of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.so as a monoid$\varprojlim_{t\mapsto t^p}\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the monoid of tilt of $C_p$ which is an algebraicly closed field in char p. and this is another reason that the the multiplicative structure on $\mathbb{C}$ and inverse limit are very different from each other

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added point 4 in edits, there is a good multiplicative structure. Does this give isomorphism ?

Comment: @har_b as I said in the post the p-th power map is isomorphism on the inverse limit but is not injective on $\mathbb{C}$ so this two group(or monoid) can not be isomorphic. in fact the whole point of taking inverse limit is that it makes the p-th power map an isomorphism(which make non prefect ring in char p prefect.\mathbb{C} is somehow like a nonprefect ring in characteristic p)

Comment: You should be somewhat careful in that the tilt is not obviously functorial with respect to NON-continuous isomorphisms. In particuar, it is not at all true that if you choose an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$ and take the tilt of the latter, that this will really not depend on your choice of isomorphism (i.e. that another isomorphism induces an isomorphism on 'titlts'). This is, no offence @har_b, just not a very useful question I think. I think you're focusing on the wrong aspects of tilts. It's an operation applied to a topological field, not an arbitrary one.

Comment: @you are right the topology is important because we know $\mathbb{C}$ with its topology but we can do the tilt operation on any monoids and it does not depend on topology. I think for some person the fact that you can start from any monoid and find a somewhat universal monoid such that the p-th power map become an isomorphism is useful and interesting fact and historically people do these kind of things before the definition of the tilt.(but I agree that it is better not to talk about additive structure)

Comment: @AlexYoucis I have added more details to the question. I really would like to know if one can make this isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as a multiplicative monoid.

Comment: @ali I just want to know if there is an isomorphism to multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{C}$, see added details to the question.

Comment: @har_b no there is not read the answer or my first comment! injectiveness of  p-th power map is an invariant of a monoid.the  p-th power map is not injective for C but it is injective for the inverse limit.