# $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times \ldots $ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, monoid

Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote the field of complex numbers.

1. Is there an isomorphism  $$\underset{\text{Countable}}{\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times\ldots} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
2. Is there an isomorphism as above if each $\mathbb{C}$ is just a multiplicative monoid.
3. Let $\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{C}\backslash 0$, is there an isomorphism

$$\underset{\text{Countable}}{\mathbb{C}^\times\times\mathbb{C}^\times\times\ldots} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$$

I believe there should an isomorphism atleast in terms of cardinality. But, I have forgotten how to prove the above statements. This question is linked to [Does $\varprojlim_{t\mapsto t^p}\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3824474/824662)
where I show that the left hand side is a multiplicative monoid of the form $$\underset{\text{Countable}}{\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times\ldots} $$ and I seek an isomorphism to the right.

Comment: For parts 1 and 3, what kind of isomorphism are you asking for? Isomorphisms of groups?

Comment: Set theoretic is fine, but if you have other isomorphisms please suggest.

Comment: @har_b A set theoretic isomorphism is just a bijection.  I don't think that's what you want.  But if it *really and truly is what you want*, well then yeah, those two have the same cardinality: $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @JunderscoreH Any link to reference would be appreciated. Ideally, I would like an answer to 2 above, that is $\mathbb{C}$ considered as a multiplicative monoid.

Comment: This question seems to be pure set theory or pure algebra, and has nothing to do with general topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, as the type of isomorphisms is unclear in the question, you may ask the question for topological structures as well, or for topological monoids, rings, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2)) No, because the monoid from the right-hand side has no zero divisors, whereas the monoid from the right-hand side has.

3)) Monoids (in fact, groups) from the left-hand side and the right-hand side are not isomorphic, because for each prime $p$ the former has $\frak c$ elements of order $p$ , whereas the latter has only $p$ such elements.